# Retrieve Non-Duplicate Data With Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to retrieve non-duplicate data with criteria based on 2 tables in SQL Server database.

**Table Subject**

```
ID       NAME                                       COURSE
-------  -----------------------------------------  ---------------------------------
SUB1234  SOFTWARE QUALITY AND PROCESS MANAGEMENT    AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM
SUB2234  SOFTWARE QUALITY AND PROCESS MANAGEMENT 1  AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM
SUB3234  SOFTWARE QUALITY AND PROCESS MANAGEMENT 2  AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM
```

**Table Result**

```
ID       SUBJECT  RESULT
-------  -------  ------
STU0001  SUB1234  NULL
```

Desired Output:

1. Get SUB2234 and SUB3234 from table Subject when ID = STU0001 and Course = AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM.

Using query below, I only able to retrieve non-duplicate data.

```
SELECT SUB.ID, SUB.NAME
FROM SUBJECT SUB LEFT JOIN
     RESULT RES
     ON RES.SUBJECT = SUB.ID
WHERE RES.SUBJECT IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you please share desired output in form of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gets the desired result.

```
SELECT SUB.ID, SUB.NAME
  FROM SUBJECT SUB 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM RESULT RES
                    WHERE RES.ID = 'STU0001'
                      AND RES.SUBJECT = SUB.ID)
   AND SUB.COURSE = 'AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM';
```

Basically the query gets all the subjects where course = 'AUPAS AMERICAN UNIVERSITY PROGRAM' and excludes the ones the students is already associated with.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

think this is what you're after

```
select res.id as student, sub.id as 'subject'
from @result res, @subject sub
where sub.id != res.subj
```